# How to define variable only once in JavaScript not on every loop in background script. chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, variables, google-chrome-extension, var

I was recently building a chrome extension so in that I had an ad blocker so i created the option to enable and disable it but I ran into a problem I am not able to define The Filters.....

In the following code how do I define `Filter` only once and not on every loop..

```js
const defaultFilters = [
  "*://*.doubleclick.net/*",
  "*://partner.googleadservices.com/*",
  ...
  "*://*.zukxd6fkxqn.com/*",
  "*://*.zy16eoat1w.com/*",
]

var Filter = Filter;

chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
     port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
           var Filter = defaultFilters;
           if (msg = 'ADBLOCK_ENABLED') {
             var Filter = defaultFilters;
           } else {
             var Filter = [''];
           }
     });
})

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { return { cancel: true }},
    { urls: Filter },
    ["blocking"]
)
```

Comment: There is no loop. You're attaching a listener that can fire at any point in time any amount of times.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is assignment, `==` or `===` is comparison.

You need to define Filter ONCE and assign where needed - here a ternary is useful

```js
const defaultFilters = [
  "*://*.doubleclick.net/*",
  "*://partner.googleadservices.com/*",
  ...
  "*://*.zukxd6fkxqn.com/*",
  "*://*.zy16eoat1w.com/*",
]

var Filter = defaultFilters; // now a global variable

chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    Filter = msg === 'ADBLOCK_ENABLED' ? defaultFilters : ['']; // use default if adblock
  });
})

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    return {
      cancel: true
    }
  }, {
    urls: Filter
  }, ["blocking"]
)
```

Comment: So perhaps onBeforeRequest is running before onConnect. Change `var Filter;` to `var Filter = defaultFilters;`

Comment: i tried adding `while(true){}` after `var Filter = defaultFilters;` until the end of code.
my [browser](https://imgur.com/a/S9qGz7y) got hanged and stopped Working

Comment: That makes no sense to do that. Event listeners run all the time and do not need to be added more than once

Comment: If you have `var Filter = defaultFilters;` you should no longer get error assuming urls expect an array

Comment: im not getting any error but when i swich off adblocker then reload a site i dont see ads

Comment: should i give the popup.js

Comment: I have no idea what you mean